# Find a pattern and replace the pattern by adding a newline in front of it

Tags: unix

Would like to replace a pattern with newline and preserving the pattern -

Sample input

```
:16R:ABC:20C::CORP:30E::ABC
```

would like to replace the pattern ":[0-9][0-9]" with a new line along with ":[0-9][0-9]" pattern

```
Output
:16R:ABC
:20C::CORP
:30E::ABC
```

Currently came up with -

```
echo ":16R:ABC:20C::CORP:30E::ABC" | sed 's/[:][0-9][0-9]/\
:/g;/^$/!P;D'

:R:ABC
:C::CORP
:E::ABC
```

Expected Output:

```
:16R:ABC
:20C::CORP
:30E::ABC
```

It's not preserving the pattern , any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a straightforward `sed` solution, POSIX-ly

```
sed 's/[A-Z]\([:][0-9][0-9][A-Z]\)/\n\1/g'
```

If you can use `awk` and have the GNU variant available, you can call `patsplit()` to split on the pattern `:[0-9][0-9][A-Z]` and start replacing from the 2nd occurrence onwards

```
awk '{ n = patsplit($0, arr, /[:][0-9][0-9][A-Z]/)
       for (iter = 2; iter <= n; iter++) 
           sub(arr[iter], ORS arr[iter]); 
     }1'
```

or with any POSIX awk

```
awk '{ n = split($0, arr, /[:]/)
       for (iter = 3; iter <= n; iter++) 
           if ( match(arr[iter], /[0-9][0-9][a-zA-Z]/) ) 
               sub(":"arr[iter], ORS ":" arr[iter]);  
     }1'
```